# ResourceType: Skipping entry 0x108034f in package table 0 because it is not complex

Tags: java, android

I have a problem with a drawer action bar in my application, in the API 21 it's work absolutely good, but in others less API, its not working.
i get this message in the Logcat  `ResourceType: Skipping entry 0x108034f in package table 0 because it is not complex!`
i look about it in my R file i don't find it.
also in the running of my app in API less than 21 the action bar is gone.
[picture where it doesn't work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2K4SB.png)
[image]

and this is the picture where it's work good
[picture where its work good](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7sYGH.png)
[image]

Thanks advance